# What, exactly is 'fixed' in a Fixed Release Distro

Tags: release-management

If I use a fixed release distribution (Ubuntu/Mint) as opposed to a rolling release distro, exactly what is not updated, what is 'fixed' in place? I update the kernel whenever a new version becomes available and routinely use `dist-upgrade` over `apt-get upgrade`. What updates or features am I missing out on by not using a rolling release?

Comment: http://www.zdnet.com/article/rolling-release-vs-fixed-release-linux/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends a lot on the distribution in question. For Ubuntu, the upgrades are governed by the [Stable Release Updates policy](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates). It's a long page, but I'll just quote section 2:

> #### 2. When
>
> Stable release updates will, in general, only be issued in order to
>   fix **high-impact bugs**. Examples of such bugs include:
>
> - Bugs which may, under realistic circumstances, directly cause a **security vulnerability**. These are done by the security team and are documented at [SecurityTeam/UpdateProcedures](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/UpdateProcedures).
> - Bugs which represent **severe regressions** from the previous release of Ubuntu. This includes packages which are totally unusable,
>     like being uninstallable or crashing on startup.
> - Bugs which may, under realistic circumstances, directly cause a **loss of user data**
> - Bugs which do not fit under above categories, but (1) have an obviously safe patch and (2) affect an application rather than
>     critical infrastructure packages (like X.org or the kernel).
> - For Long Term Support releases we regularly want to enable new hardware. Such changes are appropriate provided that we can ensure not
>     to affect upgrades on existing hardware. For example, modaliases of
>     newly introduced drivers must not overlap with previously shipped
>     drivers.
> - New versions of commercial software in the Canonical partner archive.
> - **FTBFS** (Fails To Build From Source) can also be considered. Please note that in **main** the release process ensures that there
>     are no binaries which are not built from a current source. Usually
>     those bugs should only be SRUed in conjunction with another bug fix.
>
> For new upstream versions of packages which provide new features, but
>   don't fix critical bugs, a backport should be requested instead.

Exceptions like the kernel are documented in the section on [Special Cases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates#Special_Cases).